# Total Amount is always zero

Tags: vb.net

My interface is this. (the numbers are its prices)

[image]

Inside the frame "T-shirt" all the radio button has this code:

```
Dim num1 As Integer 

    num1 = [Price]
```

In the frame Pants I put the code:

```
Dim num2 As Integer

    num2 = [Price]
```

So this is the process..

Ex. When you click the small in Tshirt Frame and the large in Pants Frame they will add and will be multiply on the Quantity (Textbox).

So I put this code in the Total Amount (Commandbutton):

```
Label3.Caption = (num1 + num2) * Val(TextBox1.Text)
```

But every time I Run the program, I always get Zero(0) on the Total Amount Label (Label3)..

I don't what is the problem with my codes.

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: @rhughes Yes.. I still can't figure out the problem

Comment: Is `Val(TextBox1.Text)` successfully parsing the number and are `num1` and `num2` filled with the correct values?

Comment: @keyboardP I tried removing Val(TextBox1.Text) in the Total Amount (Command Button) But I also get zero in Label3.Caption = (num1 + num2). But I don't think that there is something wrong in my codes declaration. Plus, I tried Label3.Caption = Val(TextBox1.Text), obviously it's working.

Comment: But now that I mentioned it, I think there's a problem in the declaration because I tried Label3.Caption = num1 and click the Total Amount, and no answer. Same with num2. Aha :/

Comment: Is this VB.NET or classic VB? Looks like classic one. show the code of your radiobutton event.

Comment: The Classic One. Haha We are using VB in the powerpoint :)

Answer (score 3):

The num1 and num2 variable aren't accesable by the button.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim num1, num2 as double

Private Sub RadioButton1_Checked
num1 = 100
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButtonn2_Checked
num1 = 150
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_Checked
num2 = 100
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton4_Checked
num2 = 150
End Sub
```

Then do your button as you are.

Comment: Uhhh.. I don't actually get that. I haven't encountered that "Public Class Form1 Dim num1, num2 as double" so I actually don't know where it should be put. But I guess It's the same way as "Dim num2 As Integer num2 = 120" I guess? XD I'm gonna search more about that. But I tried changing _Click into _Checked. But it doesn't work :< But Thanks for that :) New things, awesome

Comment: Double Click on the Radio button in the design form. That will get you to where you add num2 = [price] After you have done that, look at the top of your code, and below where it says Public Class Form1 (or whatever your form is names) add the dim x, y, as integer or whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really a fan of the RadioButton's Checked Event,
use CheckedChanged instead:

```
'T-Shirt
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged
num1 = 100
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButtonn2_CheckedChanged
num1 = 150
End Sub

'Pants
Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged
num2 = 100
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton4_CheckedChanged
num2 = 150
End Sub
```

Comment: It still doesn't work :< But thanks a lot. I'm gonna search more about that _CheckedChanged for future use. XD

Comment: I see, Maybe there's something wrong with what I did. I'll try again :) Thank you

Comment: So you are using Classic VB on Access, I dont know if the radiobutton there has the CheckedChanged Property.

Comment: I don't think it has. Because every time I change it, and double click the radio button again, it always come back as _Click and _CheckedChanged will be another code on the same radio button. I hope you get me. Haha It's kinda confusing when I explain things. Sorry